# need help regarding the docker implementation

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am actually new to docker. I have taken basic tutorials on docker and know the commands to docker regarding images, containers.

Now, All my applications servers like running on tomcat9 or nginx and also services like redis , scylla db , activemq are running on the ubuntu servers and installation,everything I am doing it manually.

I am confused like to how to start implementing the docker in my company.

Like for the commercial use, what are the prerequisites, is docker hub account neccessary or else can we use directly like docker pull image_name?

I have searched in many blogs, but could not find the way of implementation.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install docker on your computer/server first.
2. Use you cmd/bash/terminal to interact with docker. Just to make sure Docker is installed on you computer by typing on cmd `docker ps`
   If you are using Docker Desktop, you can use Docker desktop to check as well.
3. Search on hub.docker the image you need. Follow it's instruction, make a cmd `docker pull <image>` to pull their image first
4. Use `docker run` to run you image, if you image need to use a port, make sure that port isn't used by another process.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).